# What are all the ways of launching a shell from inside emacs and what are their various properties?

Tags: eshell, shell, term, ansi-term

I know of at least four possibilities:

- eshell
- term
- ansi-term
- shell

What's the complete list of tools built-in to emacs to launch a shell, and what benefits and drawbacks do they offer?

Comment: this is an interesting example of a [tag:big-list] question.  It seems that some people on the site (including the two of us) like this sort of question, whereas others really don't.  The results can be really variable depending on moderator response.  I've started a discussion on meta about it, referencing this question as an example http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/305/should-we-have-a-big-list-tag-like-tex-se-does

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`M-x shell` is the standard interface to OS's shell. On linux, it calls bash (or whatever your default), on Windows, it calls cmd.exe. `M-x shell` is the most frequently used.

`M-x eshell` is a shell written in emacs lisp entirely. It has a syntax similar to bash, but is integrated with elisp well. e.g. you can eval elisp code right there. Eshell is especially useful on Windows when you don't have cygwin etc installed.

`M-x term` and `M-x ansi-term` are terminal emulations, much like gnome-terminal, xterm, etc. The main difference to `M-x shell` is that, in `eshell` or `shell`, keys are still emacs keys, but in `term`, emacs keys doesn't work. But, the advantage is that you can run ssh, vim, or any command that are text-UI based, which won't work in `M-x eshell` or `M-x shell`.

`term` and `ansi-term` used to be different packages, but now they are 2 different commands in the same file term.el. I haven't used them much. You can find a more detailed answer about this on [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm).

There is some more information on [my blog](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_shell_vs_term_vs_ansi-term_vs_eshell.html).

Comment: "now are 2 different commands the same file". There may be a missing word or two there.

Comment: Good answer. A link to the wiki page mentioned would be nice too.

Comment: "M-x shell is the most frequently used"--I'd want a citation or some data to support that, since I'm not at all convinced that it's true. Also, it adds nothing substantive to the answer. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: shosti, i don't have hard statistics. according to the file header, shell is 1988. eshell is 1999. term.el is also 1988. eshell is mostly used by elisp hackers, so that's much fewer than emacs users. That leaves shell vs term. I think we can compare their mention in emacs books, e.g. the 3 or so old ones from O'Reilly. Or Google comparison... but just from experience hanging around in emacs community, i think term/ansi-term is much less used.