# TERM, terminfo, termcap. What are they how does Emacs use it?

Tags: shell, term

I have a few questions about the relationship between `TERM`, `terminfo` and `termcap` and Emacs.

- I do not know **exactly** what `TERM`, `terminfo` and `termcap` are.
- I am on OS X.  I do not know **what** values (and **where**) I should set variables such as `TERM`.

But since such information is not really about Emacs I will seek it elsewhere.

With respect to *Emacs*, my question is this: *How are such things are used by Emacs by `shell` and `ansi-term`?*

Comment: Start with this response: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/242/7045

Comment: Another inevitable question answered: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2743/7045

Comment: Thanks @EmacsUser I read through those answers and already knew that info.

Comment: Only one question per question, please. And it should be about *Emacs*. I edited your question to the only Emacs question I saw in it. Feel free to edit it further, to better clarify just what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) and [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) are both methods for an application running in a terminal to obtain information about the terminal — what it can do and how (e.g. its size, how to move the cursor around, etc.). Both consist of a database that associates terminal capability descriptions to terminal names, as well as a library of code to query the database.

The `TERM` environment variable gives the terminal name, which applications look up in the database. Some applications also support the environment variable `TERMCAP` which describes the terminal capabilities in termcap format. There is also an environment variable `TERMINFO`, but it contains the location of the terminal database files, not the actual terminal description.

**In general, you should not set `TERM`**. The terminal emulator sets it for you, or the OS configuration for a hardware terminal. Remote login methods (e.g. ssh, telnet) copy the local value of `TERM` to the remote host, but typically don't propagate `TERMCAP` or `TERMINFO`.

Shell mode sets `TERM` to `dumb`, a terminal that can basically do nothing other than display output line by line. Term (`M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term`) sets `TERM` to `eterm-color` (this can be configured by setting the variable `term-term-name`), and also sets `TERMINFO` and `TERMCAP`.

The problem with termcap and terminfo is that they work optimally only if everyone has the same name→information database, which is not the case with remote logins. You can sometimes end up with a terminal name that's known locally, but not known on the remote host. And sometimes terminal emulators set `TERM` to a widely-supported name that only declares a subset of their capabilities, so as to work even on machines that don't have anything better in their database. In such cases, you might want to set `TERM` manually. For example, if you log in to a machine that doesn't know `eterm-color`, you might set `TERM` to `eterm` or `vt100` instead ([`vt100`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) is a subset of most terminals' capabilities), either by setting `term-term-name` in Emacs if you open a Term buffer just to log in to that machine, or by setting `TERM` from your shell login script.

Comment: See also [eterm-color: Unknown terminal type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22083177/324105) for how to make a server recognise `eterm-color`.

Answer (score 6):

`TERM` is an environment variable, you set it in your environment. This could be the environment of a particular shell that you've opened, by running `export TERM=foo`, or all of your shells by adding the same command to your .bashrc (or a similar file for your shell, if you don't use bash. but you probably do use bash).

`terminfo` and `termcap` are databases containing information about terminals. A terminal was originally a hardware device that combined a display and a keyboard. Your computer would send commands to your terminal to tell it what to display, and of course the terminal would send most keyboard input to the computer (it would handle some keyboard input itself). These days your terminal is a software program running on the computer, but programs still talk to the terminal as if it were an external piece of hardware. The value you set this variable to depends on what program you're running. If you're running XTerm, then set it to "xterm". If you're running RXVT, then set it to "rxvt". And so on.

Anyway, the terminals were all designed and built by different companies who were all in competition with each other, and so they were all adding features as quickly as possible in order to out-do each other. Naturally, none of these companies designed their terminals using the same command set as their competitors; the sort of standardization we have with HTML and CSS today didn't exist back then. The `termcap` database was created to let you use any terminal you happened to want with your computer. A program could query the `termcap` database to find out what commands to use for your terminal. Ultimately the program wouldn't need to know anything about any particular terminal; it would just ask `termcap` how to do everything.

`terminfo` is a newer database than `termcap`. It contains essentially the same information, and can be considered interchangeable with `termcap`.

Programs that use `termcap` or `terminfo` look at the `TERM` environment variable to know what kind of terminal you're using; they pass the value along to the database when they make their queries.

The emacs `shell` and `eshell` modes are not really considered terminal emulators; they don't provide any capabilities for changing the text color or moving the cursor around.

`term` and `ansi-term`, on the other hand, provide essentially all the features you would expect from a mid-range terminal such as a VT100, or xterm. I don't actually know off-hand what `TERM` should be set to for these, but I think they set it for you.